# Cascading windows question (reset start location?)

Tags: swift, macos

I have several reports that I'm displaying each in their own window.
My WindowController is set to cascade them:

```
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super .init(coder: coder)
        
        shouldCascadeWindows = true
    }
```

Then, when they are needed to be displayed, I instantiate them in a loop and add them to an array, like this :

```
                let bwc : NSWindowController = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(identifier: "BatchReportWindowController") as BatchWindowController
                bwc.window?.title = batch.lastPathComponent
                bwc.showWindow(self)
                
                let vc = bwc.contentViewController as? BatchViewController
                vc!.updateInfoTableView(withInfo: ingestInformation)
                
                batchesWindowControllers.append(bwc)
```

Whenever I run the code where a new set of these report window are displayed they cascade as expected, however they pick up where they left off the last time a series of them was displayed, rather than starting from the beginning (if that makes sense).

How would I make the series of window start at the same point (then cascade from there) whenever I needed to display a series of them?

Comment: Have you tried setting the position of the first window? Or `shouldCascadeWindows = false` for the first window?

Comment: @Willeke, you are probably right that this will work.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way to just reset the cascade of windows each time they need to be displayed.

Comment: The cascade can be reset by deallocating all windows, by not cascading or by moving the window. Is the window position autosaved?

Comment: @Willeke, thank you!
I never removed the WindowControllers from the array that was holding them. Now that my closeReports method now removes them from the array (as well as closes them) the cascade start location resets.

Comment: @Willeke Cool find. Want to right that up into an answer?

Comment: `bwc.window?.title =` You should avoid this, as it's silencing a potential error. If your window is `nil`, you'll want to know about it, rather than silently not setting its title.

Comment: @Alexander, good catch – and definitely best practice. (very unlikely to be an issue in this particular case but I do need to learn and adopt good practices going forward.)